# constant with convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $x_n \to x$  in distribution as $n \to \infty $, and $c\in\Bbb{R}$.  Prove that

1. $x_n +c \to x+c$  in distribution
2. $cx_n \to cx$ in distribution

I know F(Xn)→FXasn→∞
but in proof 1 can I do this step $F(Xn+c)(x)<F(xn)+c$

Please help me ! Any hints ?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is a continuous and bounded function of $x$, so are $f(x+x)$ and $cf(x)$.

Comment: how i does these in the proof @kimchilover

Comment: So what's your definition of "convergence in distribution"?  More generally, what have you tried so far?  What is the most difficult problem in this area that you *have* solved so far?

Comment: I know $F_(X_n) \to F_X as n \to \infty$ but in proof 1 can I do this  step $F_(X_n +c) (x) < F_(x_n) +c $ @kimchilover

Comment: So you know $F_n(t)\to F(t)$ at all continuity points of $F$, and want to show that $G_n(u)\to G(u)$ at all continuity points of $G$, where $F_n$ is the cdf of $x_n$ and $G_n$ is the cdf of $x_n+c)$, and $F$ and $G$ are the cdf of $x$ and $x+c$.  Work out a formula for $G_n$ in terms of $F_n$, and go on from there.  Similarly for the multiplication formula, with $H_n$ and $H$, the cdfs of $cx_n$ and $cx$.

Comment: F_{X_n}+c(x)= p(X_n +c <x) what now i use to arreach to X+c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70841/discussion-between-nikola-and-kimchi-lover).